# Why in Edge on Windows 10 version 20H2, when I open a link from an .exe file: in addition to the real link, an empty tab gets opened?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

This happens also when I open a link from iCUE software for my many buttons Corsair mouse, and when I open a link from my OMEN SteelSeries Engine 3 many keys keyboard.

Edge is updated and Windows 10 is updated, what's the chance that when my Windows 10 21H1 update becomes available and I install it this would be solved?

Comment: The question in the title is probably answerable (not by me though) but the question in the text asks for pure speculation.

Comment: What exe is causing this? Did you try resetting Edge (Settings, Apps)?  Did you try a new, temporary Windows User Account?  Same issue in multiple accounts?

Comment: 21H1 just came out. Updating now.

Comment: 21H1 came out but not for everyone yet; The exe that is causing it is one made in VS C# of Process.Start(URL);

Comment: I left two other suggestions, so you should try them.

Comment: Installing 21H1 (if you can even call it that) won't solve this problem since that will be done through an enablement package.  The problem likely is the iCUE software itself.  This is especially evident if it actually is written in C# and using the legacy WebView library.

Comment: The problem is not in iCUE, because also when I run an exe file I created with only a Process.Start(URL); line in it in C# Visual Studio WinForms, a new empty page gets opened in addition to the real one, as for the hassle to try many things now I'm living with the open tabs and close them every while.

Comment: I'm waiting for an Edge update or Windows update to solve this, maybe that's caused by an extension in Edge, but I don't have power for the hassle of testing I will wait as maybe it gets solved alone maybe also by extensions' developers.